# В Android Studio не удаляется проект, скачанный из GitHub.

Tags: android, android-studio, github

Я пытаюсь удалить файл с проектом, скачанным из GitHub. Но после удаления он снова появляется в папке AndroidStudioProjects. При входе в Android Studio он начинает скачиваться заново. Как его удалить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты видимо не удаляешь его. Просто в главном окне Android Studio нажимаешь на Крестик? это бесполезно.

А то что он загружается у тебя в настройках студии установленно чтобы проект при старте грузился.

Удали просто саму папку проекта. Допустим проект называется Project2017 в основном по стандарту все проекты находятся в папке AndroidStudioProject. Вот оттуда и удали Project2017. А после запусти Android Studio и все

Comment: Я удаляю папку с проектом. Она иcчезает из папки AndroidStudioProjects, но потом опять появляется. Эта проблема только с проектом скачанным из GitHub. Остальные нормально удаляются.